# Evaluate the integral $\int _\gamma (e{^z}^{2} + \overline{z}) dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

First part of the question asks me to state the path integral $\int_\gamma f$, which I defined as:
\begin{equation}
\int_\gamma f = \int^b_a f(\gamma(t))\gamma ' (t) dt
\end{equation}

And the second part asks to evaluate the integral 
\begin{equation}
\int _\gamma (e{^z}^{2} + \overline{z}) dz
\end{equation}
where $\gamma$ is the positively oriented unit circle.

Does this mean that $\gamma(t) = e^t + t \ (0 \leq t \leq 1) $ ?

Comment: $\gamma (t) = e^{2 \pi i t} \quad t \in (0,1)$, is a fairly standard parameterization of the unit circle

Comment: I think inside the integral you have $\;e^{z^2}\;$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Since $e^{z^2}$ is analytic on and inside the curve given and since $\overline{z}=1/z$ on this curve, the integral is $0 + 2\pi i$.